# Svelte 3, async onMount or a valid alternative?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

What I need is to use `async-await` in Svelte `onMount()`.

*Or maybe you can suggest me what is wrong and what I can use alternatively.*

**To Reproduce**

1. go here: https://svelte.dev/repl/000ae69c0fe14d9483678d4ace874726?version=3.23.0
2. open the console
3. click on the button
4. you should see messages: `"Mounting..."` and `"A lot of background work..."`
5. if you click again the destroy message is not written

**WHY?**

Did `onMount()` recognizes the `async` function promise? Should it?

I need that `async` behavior because I need to wait for `function lazyLoading()` before rendering the `Child` component.

**Is there an alternative way to do this in Svelte?**

Comment: Look at `{#await}`: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `#await` and `onMount`, both?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what you'd want to do at `onMount` then. Check out my example: https://svelte.dev/repl/7e175db016b74c4ba4688c76114866c9?version=3.23.0

Comment: Hm let me put that into an actual answer...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just to explain why `onMount` can't be an `async` function (this *might* change in future, but don't expect it to):

You can return a function from an `onMount` handler that is called when the component is destroyed. But `async` functions can *only return a promise*. Since a promise isn't a function, Svelte will ignore the return value.

This is the same as `useEffect` in React, incidentally — the function must be synchronous in order to avoid race conditions. The recommended solution for `onMount` is the same as for `useEffect` — place an `async` function *inside* the handler:

```js
onMount(() => {
  async function foo() {
    bar = await baz();
  }

  foo();

  return () => console.log('destroyed');
});
```

(Note that you're responsible for handling any race conditions that arise as a result of the component being destroyed before the promise resolves, though assigning state inside a destroyed component is harmless.)

I've opened an issue to discuss providing more useful feedback in these situations: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4944

Comment: I have a question about this. In the sapper docs, under https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Making_a_component_SSR_compatible onMount is used with an `async` keyword. Doesn't this contradict your statement about `onMount` not being asynchronous? This confuses me, is there something I don't see?

Comment: Does this imply that when you don't need a destroy function, it is okay to use async?

Comment: Yes, that's totally valid

Comment: Now, you can use `async` function inside `onMount` hook. See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount.

Comment: @LaodeMuhammadAlFatih No, this isn't true, afaik. Since this documentation page has the async key word for long time and was always 'wrong' and confusing. But Rich wrote it: it is okay to use it, as long as you don't need to return a destroy function.

Answer (score 6):

`onMount` must be synchronous. However, you can use [an `{#await}` block](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks) in your markup and make `lazyLoading` `async`, for example:

```html
{#await lazyLoading() then data}
  I'm the child and I loaded "{data}".
{/await}
```

You could also do...

```html
<script>
  let dataPromise = lazyLoading()
</script>

{#await dataPromise then data}
  I'm the child and I loaded "{data}".
{/await}
```

See my working example [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/7e175db016b74c4ba4688c76114866c9?version=3.23.0).

This has the additional benefit of allowing you to use a loader as well as markup that appears when the promise is rejected, using this syntax:

```html
{#await promise}
  loading
{:then value}
  loaded {value}
{:catch error}
  failed with {error}
{/await}
```

Comment: It is interesting that it still works when making it async, only that the clean up breaks. Is there a reason why it does not work async, like it does in React?

Comment: For clarity, React has the exact same limitation — your `useEffect` handler (the nearest equivalent to `onMount`) must return a cleanup function synchronously, to avoid race conditions.