# @urql/svelte, "Function called outside component initialization" if not in onMount

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, urql

I'm trying the amazing works done by https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/tree/master/packages/svelte-urql guys.

Everything works good until today issue.

I'm using the below code and it gives me this error:

```
Error: Function called outside component initialization
  at get_current_component (index.mjs:615)
  at getContext (index.mjs:648)
  at getClient (urql-svelte.mjs:55)
  at query (urql-svelte.mjs:81)
  at Players.svelte:41
```

Code:

```
<script>
  import { query } from '@urql/svelte'
  import { myQuery } from './myQuery'

  let players
  let myVars

  function sleep (ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
  }

  $: (async () => {
    await sleep(2000) // this gives me the error; removing it make it work
    players = query({
      query: myQuery,
      variables: { ...myVars },
      requestPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
    })
  })()
</script>

{#if !players}
  Loading players...
{:else}
  Players loaded! Do the work.
{/if}
```

**Can you suggest what's the problem?**

If I use `await()` in `onMount()` it works! Like this:

```js
onMount(async () => {
  await sleep(2000)
  loaded = true
})
```

Here the code for `@urql/svelte`:

1. query.ts: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/blob/master/packages/svelte-urql/src/operations/query.ts
2. context.ts: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/blob/master/packages/svelte-urql/src/context.ts

Maybe the `context` code?

```
import { setContext, getContext } from 'svelte';
import { Client, ClientOptions } from '@urql/core';

const CLIENT = '$$_URQL';

export const getClient = (): Client => getContext(CLIENT);

export const setClient = (client: Client): void => {
  setContext(CLIENT, client);
};

export const initClient = (args: ClientOptions): Client => {
  const client = new Client(args);
  setClient(client);
  return client;
};
```

*I can create a REPL on CodeSandbox if you need, no problem.*

*Bug on `@urql/svelte`: [https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/issues/795.](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/issues/795._)*

**Information about your Svelte project:**
- Chrome 83
- Svelte version: 3.23.0
- Rollup

Comment: Seems like these reactive statements don't like asynchronous functions. Do you need it for your logic? Why don't you use the await blocks from your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087073/svelte-3-async-onmount-or-a-valid-alternative

Answer (score 2):

If using Vite as a bundler, you will need to exclude `@urql/svelte` from dependency pre-bundling, which apparently caused this error for me.

Add this to your Vite config:

```js
{
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['@urql/svelte']
  }
}
```

This also works for `svelte-apollo`, do the same but replace the package name!

Docs on Vite's [dependency pre-bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html) are there, if curious.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was a bit different, but got the same error. In my case, I was trying to get Svelte/Sapper running in a Docker container for development purposes. I was fiddling around with the `package.json` before this and at some point I decided to move `svelte` and `sapper` to "dependencies" instead of "devDependencies".

```
"dependencies": {
    // ...
    "sapper": "^0.27.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
}
```

**This was a bad idea.** Once I moved it back to "devDependencies", the error went away and everything worked as expected.

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "sapper": "^0.27.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
}
```

I hope this helps someone down the line.

Comment: I would have _never_ guessed this could have been the issue but it sure was for me. Thanks! I think what's happening is that, since svelte's whole thing is not shipping framework code to the client, all its stuff needs to be in devDependencies. In my case, it was svelte-apollo that was in the wrong place.